# PyQt QMovie will not loop GIF

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I have a working example of playing a **gif**, but it isn't looping the GIF. Even i changed **movie.setCacheMode(QMovie.CacheAll)**

Any Idea?
[image] -->Animated Gif

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

import sys

class ImagePlayer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, filename, title, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        # Load the file into a QMovie
        self.movie = QMovie(filename, QByteArray(), self)

        size = self.movie.scaledSize()
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, size.width(), size.height())
        self.setWindowTitle(title)

        self.movie_screen = QLabel()
        # Make label fit the gif
        self.movie_screen.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.movie_screen.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        # Create the layout
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.movie_screen)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

        # Add the QMovie object to the label
        self.movie.setCacheMode(QMovie.CacheAll)
        self.movie.setSpeed(100)
        self.movie_screen.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()
        self.movie.loopCount()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gif = "dotGreen.gif"
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = ImagePlayer(gif, "was")
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the **gif** was saved before with the Looping Option **play once**. So changing it to "**Forever**" did the trick.

[image: Photoshop Gif export with Forever Option]

Comment: I am trying to make this work but mine still won't loop. I set the cache mode to CacheAll and verified that the loop count was set to forever but it still isn't looping. Any ideas?